# What are the registration_ids in creating a Device Group?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an Android application with Login Functionality. User can login from multiple devices using the same credentials (email and password). I would likes to send notifications to the user when a server instant occurs.

As per my understanding from the docs from Google FCM,

1. Needs to create a group in FCM with unique `notification_key_name` (usually user id or email). Then add devices to it like below

> ```
> https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification
> Content-Type:application/json
> Authorization:key=SERVER_KEY
> project_id:SENDER_ID
>
> {
>    "operation": "create",
>    "notification_key_name": "appUser-Chris",
>    "registration_ids": ["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
> }
> ```

As a result FCM returns a `notification_key`.

My question is what is this `registration_ids`(`["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]`) refers to?

Are those from application database like user-id in table?

Not mentioned about these `registration_ids` in the following docs

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications

Answer (score 1):

`registration_ids` refer to each device unique key generated using FCM from the respective client

Ex: you can refer [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) doc to get the token(registration_id) for android

In your case, If the user can log-in to multiple devices, then each device will send a token from the user, you should store all the device registration_id for the user.

Updated:
For Group message we should create notification_key using the registeration_ids from the multiple users, in that case instead of sending multiple user ones by one we can use the notification_key.

Comment: but in case of group messaging, a notification key is required for sending notifications to all devices belongs to that group. ie a group will share a notification key. Am I right ?

Comment: I updated the answer, if you want to send to all device, you can generate a notification_key using that device and you can send a message to that notification_key it will send to all devices(Note: It's for each device not for each user, if user have multiple devices we should add all the registeration_ids)

Comment: yes. but what is a registration_id ? from where I will get that ? In docs it was mentioned like 4,15,48,55 etc

Comment: That is  registration tokens from each device(or client)

Comment: My bad! totally confusion. I think each element in 4,5,15,48 are point to each device right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170031/discussion-between-ramesh-and-muthukrishnan-rajendran).